# How to disable occupied dates in daterangepicker JS and Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I'm trying to implement a resort booking where I can check if a specific date is still available or not by using [`bootstrap daterangepicker`](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) but I can't figure out how to do this. I got [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425757/how-to-disable-already-booked-dates) but it is not using `daterangepicker`.

Note: I'm also using laravel5.1 so maybe this can help the problem.

**Database fields**

`id`
`name`
`Place`
`start_time`
`end_time`

**My JS Code Setup with daterangepicker**

```
$(function () {
    $('.time').daterangepicker({
        "minDate": moment('{{ date('Y-m-d G') }}'),
        "timePicker": true,
        "showDropdowns": true,
        "timePicker24Hour": false,
        "timePickerIncrement": 5,
        "autoApply": true,
        "locale": {
            "format": "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A",
            "separator": " — ",
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I cannot use comments so I'm writing here. You can check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40670141/how-to-disable-specific-date-range-in-bootstrap-daterangepicker

Comment: But that is a specific date, not the range of the date

Answer (score 1):

You want to ideally, use the `isInvalidDate` configuration option when creating a new instance of the daterangepicker.

```
isInvalidDate

var disabledDates = {{ $disabledDates->toJson(); }};

$(function () {
    $('.time').daterangepicker({
        "minDate": moment('{{ date('Y-m-d G') }}'),
        "timePicker": true,
        "showDropdowns": true,
        "timePicker24Hour": false,
        "timePickerIncrement": 5,
        "autoApply": true,
        "locale": {
            "format": "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A",
            "separator": " — ",
        },
        "isInvalidDate": function (date) {
            return disabledDates.indexOf(date) != -1;
        }
    });
});
```

The `$disabledDates` php variable in this instance, is assumed to be a collection of disabled dates, all as their string formats.

Comment: Hi Ollieread. What if I only have 2 dates available?  the `start_date` and the `end_date`?

Comment: @Jonjie then you can swap it around, so `disabledDates` is `enabledDates` and have the function return `disabledDates.indexOf(date) == -1`. Unless you mean a range?

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a `start_date` and a `end_date`.

```
$(function() {
    var start_date = '2018-3-1';
    var end_date = '2018-3-10';
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
      "minDate": moment('2018-1-1'),
      "timePicker": true,
      "showDropdowns": true,
      "timePicker24Hour": false,
      "timePickerIncrement": 5,
      "autoApply": true,
      "locale": {
        "format": "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A",
        "separator": " — ",
      },
      "isInvalidDate": function (date) {
        var is_valid = true;
        @foreach($dates as $date)
          if(moment(date).isBetween($date->start_date, $date->end_date, 'day', '[]')){
            is_valid = false;
          }
        @endforeach
        return is_valid;
      }
    });
  });
```

Then you can't select the day between start_date and end_date.

Comment: This would be great. I'll try it. But what if I have a lot of `start_date` and `end_data` due to lot of customers booked? (And please add the time, not just the date)

Comment: @Jonjie you can add a for loop to check whether date is between couples of `start_date` and `end_date`. But I think this plugin does not support checking time validation originally.

Comment: Hi pktanyue. Can you update it to your answer so I can evaluate and test?

Comment: @Jonjie what variables do you have now ?

Comment: I have `$dates` variables from my controller (in Laravel) that returns json of `datetime (start_date, end_date)`.

Comment: Why did you use `foreach` inside of javascript? you cannot use php code inside of javascript.

Comment: @Jonjie so you give me a variable in javajscript?

Comment: Hi @pktangyue . No, its a php variable. But, I just thinking about the `foreach` in your javascript code

Comment: @Jonjie ok, I don't know well about laravel, maybe like this? You can adjust it yourself